# br tag inside table data cell - td is not rendered

Tags: jquery, html, line-breaks

I am using br tag to display a list of strings inside a table cell. But, it is not rendering a newline but is displayed as a tag string.

See column 4,

[image]

I tried `<BR>, <br/>, </br>, <p>`. None of them are printing a newline.

I am using `Helvetica Sans-serif` font with `Jquery-ui, datatables` plugin.

I am not using monospaced fonts explicitly anywhere.

Comment: The issue is because that string is HTMLEncoded. We can't tell you exactly how that has happened, and how you can change it without seeing your code that populates the datatable. Is it encoded in your datastore?

Comment: i manually edited the innerhtml in the chrome's debug console to contain angled brackets and not encoded chars (&gt;)... still, it didnt get rendered.

Comment: First it is <br> all the tags use no uppercase. Then, the difference between <br> and <br /> is that the first works for html 5 and the other for previous versions as a valid markup. Show your header and the example of a row please

Comment: thanks Rory... yes, there are encoded angled brackets outside `br` tags even though it was not readily visible in the browser console.....

Answer (score 1):

As Rory said, the table cell content is `HTMLEncoded` causing this error.

Jquery template encodes the html content when the variables are substituted as,

```
<td>${var_name}</td>
```

This was causing the error and i corrected it by using the `jquery template - html` helper function,

```
<td>{{html var_name}}</td>
```

thanks Rory